# Custom payment method with file upload without flash player install

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-methods

How to create a custom payment method with file upload without flash player install. I already make it works using uploadify but my problem is when I run it in browser with no flash player install, including android and IOS device the upload button not showing.. I googling but no solutions in the results.. Any one can help me on this?

Comment: Give this a try https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Comment: Thanks.. I already tried it and install. My problem is I cannot able to see the form in the page. I check in the list of modules in admin it is there but I cant see it in the page thats why I cannot able to modify the code and test it . Thanks